# Change Listview color on every 20seconds

Tags: android, android-listview, background-color

[image]

Is it possible to change listview color or background color on every 10 or 15 seconds.I have used existing code for this listview. Where to add necessary step inside mycode.I don't want to change color for user everytime select item. If user simple open my app and 10seconds over backgroundcolor automatically change.

MyCode:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView lv;
    private EditText et;
    private String listview_array[] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE",
    "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN" };
    private ArrayList<String> array_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
    int textlength=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));

        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
                                                                        // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
        int start, int count, int after)
        {
        // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
        int start, int before, int count)
        {
        textlength = et.getText().length();
        array_sort.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < listview_array.length; i++)
        {
        if (textlength <= listview_array[i].length())
        {
        if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
        (String)
        listview_array[i].subSequence(0,
        textlength)))
        {
                                                                                                                        array_sort.add(listview_array[i]);
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                        }
                                                                        }
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (MainActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
        }
        });

    }
```

Comment: it is possible with custom adapter......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the getview() of the customview change color of the text view that you are inflating with.
And use notifydatasetchanged() every time you need